# Batch file if statement isn't working as expected - syntax errors?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I believe I'm having an issues with syntax in a batch file that I am trying to write. I'm new to writing batch files, and I am still learning how the language works. Essentially, I have a script that can be run with `-run` and additional commands:

```
ScriptName -run -prereq
```

I also want to be able to have a help menu for any commands that can be run with the script:

```
ScriptName -help
```

Followed by more input parameters that the user wants help for

```
** Enter any additional input commands for Script help:
```

User input would then be something like:

```
-prereq -one -two -three
```

The `-run` command should actually run and apply the commands.

The `-help` command should just echo information about the requested commands.

Just running the script with no `-run` or `-help` command prints a very basic header with version, time, and explanation that `-help` exists (as seen in code below)

Basically, `-run` should just call the processes depending on which are applied, as can be seen by the label `:process_args` similarly, `-help` will first take a `-help` command to initiate, and then it will ask for more parameters, as seen by in `:help_process_args` which will call labels that echo information.

The help functionality seems to work, but if I run the script with no `-run` parameter, it defaults to the `-run` functionality. Also, I keep seeing syntax errors as I try to fix the default behavior.

Can anyone see why `-help` works, and why the code defaults to the `-run` behavior with no parameters, instead of printing the short header? Also, are there any syntax errors that are obvious? (again, I'm new to batch files)

Here's the relevant code that shows the help menu creation and calls to run and help processes.

```
echo *********************************************
echo **
echo **     Script Version: x.x
echo **         Started at: %time%
echo **    For options use: ScriptNameHere -help
echo **
echo *********************************************

if /i [%1]==[-help] (
    echo **                 Options:
    echo *********************************************
    echo **
    echo **      -run   = Runs the script
    echo **   -prereq   = Skip prereq steps
    echo ** 
    echo ** Enter any additional input commands for Script help:
    echo **

    goto help_input

    endlocal
    exit /b 0
)
if /i [%1]==[-run] (
    call :process_args %*

    call :labelOne
    call :labelTwo
    call :labelThree

    endlocal
    exit /b 0
)
else (
    goto end
)

:help_input
set input=
set /p input= ** :

goto help_process

:help_process
call :process_help_args %input%
if /i not "%_help_opts:-echo=%"=="%_help_opts%" goto:eof

call :helpLabelOne
call :helpLabelTwo
call :helpLabelThree

:process_help_args
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /B %errorlevel%
echo. && echo * Setting Special Arguments
    :help_args_loop
    if not [%1] equ [] (
        if [%_help_opts%] neq [] set _help_opts=%_help_opts%/%1
        if [%_help_opts%] equ [] set _help_opts=%1
        echo -- Found %1
        shift
        goto help_args_loop
    ) else (
        if not defined _help_opts (
            echo * No Options Provided
            set _help_opts=**EMPTY**
        )
    )
goto:eof

:process_args
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /B %errorlevel%
echo. && echo * Setting Special Arguments
    :args_loop
    if not [%1] equ [] (
        if [%_opts%] neq [] set _opts=%_opts%/%1
        if [%_opts%] equ [] set _opts=%1
        echo -- Found %1
        shift
        goto args_loop
    ) else (
        if not defined _opts (
            echo * No Options Provided
            set _opts=**EMPTY**
        )
    )
goto:eof

:end
endlocal
echo ** Script Complete at %time%
exit /B 0
```

Comment: The `else` part must be placed in the same line of the closing parentheses of the "then" part (like in two other `if`'s you have), otherwise the "else" is taken as another command.

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't seem to give me different results. I also read that there needs to be whitespace around parentheses, so I was looking out for that as well.

Comment: Not the answer, but where are these things :LabelOne, :LabelTwo, :LabelThree, :HelpLabelOne, etc.?

Comment: @Liturgist they are examples of calls to labels that just echo information, so they shouldn't hold any significance towards this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after face-palming countless times, I think I've figured it out.

Essentially, I took the logic out of the if statements and placed them in labels, and then within the if statements, I pointed to the labels. Not sure why this works, but everything is functioning properly so I'll take it!

```
echo *********************************************
echo **
echo **     Script Version: x.x
echo **         Started at: %time%
echo **    For options use: ScriptNameHere -help
echo **
echo *********************************************

if /i [%1]==[-help] ( goto end )
if /i [%1]==[-run] ( goto end )
if /i [%1]==[] ( goto end )

:help
echo **                 Options:
echo *********************************************
echo **
echo **      -run   = Runs the script
echo **   -prereq   = Skip prereq steps
echo ** 
echo ** Enter any additional input commands for Script help:
echo **

goto help_input

endlocal
exit /b 0

:run
call :process_args %*

call :labelOne
call :labelTwo
call :labelThree

endlocal
exit /b 0

:help_input
set input=
set /p input= ** :

goto help_process

:help_process
call :process_help_args %input%
if /i not "%_help_opts:-echo=%"=="%_help_opts%" goto:eof

call :helpLabelOne
call :helpLabelTwo
call :helpLabelThree

:process_help_args
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /B %errorlevel%
echo. && echo * Setting Special Arguments
    :help_args_loop
    if not [%1] equ [] (
        if [%_help_opts%] neq [] set _help_opts=%_help_opts%/%1
        if [%_help_opts%] equ [] set _help_opts=%1
        echo -- Found %1
        shift
        goto help_args_loop
    ) else (
        if not defined _help_opts (
            echo * No Options Provided
            set _help_opts=**EMPTY**
        )
    )
goto:eof

:process_args
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /B %errorlevel%
echo. && echo * Setting Special Arguments
    :args_loop
    if not [%1] equ [] (
        if [%_opts%] neq [] set _opts=%_opts%/%1
        if [%_opts%] equ [] set _opts=%1
        echo -- Found %1
        shift
        goto args_loop
    ) else (
        if not defined _opts (
            echo * No Options Provided
            set _opts=**EMPTY**
        )
    )
goto:eof

:end
endlocal
echo ** Script Complete at %time%
exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
    endlocal
    exit /b 0
)
else (
    goto end
)
```

to

```
    endlocal
    exit /b 0
) else (
    goto end
)
```

produced the following results.

```
C:>labstuff.bat
*********************************************
**
**     Script Version: x.x
**         Started at: 13:17:55.30
**    For options use: ScriptNameHere -help
**
*********************************************
** Script Complete at 13:17:55.32
```

and

```
C:>labstuff.bat -run
*********************************************
**
**     Script Version: x.x
**         Started at: 13:16:15.62
**    For options use: ScriptNameHere -help
**
*********************************************

* Setting Special Arguments
-- Found -run
The system cannot find the batch label specified - labelOne
The system cannot find the batch label specified - labelTwo
The system cannot find the batch label specified - labelThree
```

Comment: This is the same suggestion that @Aacini made in the comment section of my question and I replied that it didn't give me any results. The issue is more than likely something with the structure of the if statements. If I simply swap the locations of the help and run if statements, none of the functionality works. As far as I understand, location shouldn't matter, so there must be something else that's breaking it.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out and I posted my answer below. Although your answer didn't seem to work for me, I appreciate the insight and efforts!